# Error from moving acts_as_taggable into an included module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

If I write this, everything works fine:

```
class A < ActiveRecord::Base
acts_as_taggable
end
```

But if I take `acts_as_taggable` and put it into a module that class A includes, I get an error:

```
module B
  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      extend ClassMethods
      include InstanceMethods
    end
  end

  module ClassMethods
    acts_as_taggable
  end

  module InstanceMethods
  end
end

class A < ActiveRecord::Base
include B
```

The error from the code above is:

```
undefined local variable or method `acts_as_taggable' for C::ClassMethods:Module
```

**Is it not correct to call `acts_as_taggable` from an included module?**

**Does it need to be in the class definition itself?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When Ruby loads the file containing your module `B` and reaches the `acts_as_taggable` line, it will try to execute the `acts_as_taggable` class method of `ClassMethods` (which doesn't exist because it is actually a class method of `ActiveRecord::Base`).

You *can* use the `included` method to call `acts_as_taggable` when your module is included though. `included` is passed the class the module is being included in, so the following will work:

```
module B
  def self.included(base)
    base.acts_as_taggable

    # ...
  end

  # ...
end
```